# Javascript - JSON String to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

This is driving me mad, I have a JSON string that looks like so:

```
[["OX", "139.38"], ["LE", "131.28"], ["SA", "105.45"]]
```

I want to convert this to an array so that I can I can take advantage of `indexOf`:

```
alert(myArray.indexOf("LE"));
```

I've tried to convert my JSON string to an array using `JSON.parse(myJSON)` and `jQuery.parseJSON(myJSON)` but neither work.

How can I create an array from my JSON string? I'm happy to set up a loop just not sure how.

Comment: Do you have anything to change the JSON?

Comment: *but neither work* - don't work **how**? What happens instead?

Comment: They say invalid characters.  I think the JSON string isn't a "true" JSON string

Comment: Include the errors you are getting, what they are related to, and the actual string. What youve included above isnt a string but an array. Whats not working specifically? also given that you have an array of arrays you would have to do `myArray[1].indexOf('LE');`

Comment: Do you want to convert it like so: [[""OX", "139.38"], ["LE", "131.28""]] -> ["OX", "139.38", "LE", "131.28"] or ["OX", "LE"]?

Answer (score 1):

This works in chrome console:

```
var s = '[["OX", "139.38"], ["LE", "131.28"], ["SA", "105.45"]]';
var a = JSON.parse(s);

// a = [["OX", "139.38"],["LE", "131.28"],["SA", "105.45"]]
```

If you want to create a data structure to lookup the values by the keys:

```
var dict = {};
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    dict[a[i][0]] = a[i][1];
}
```

Now `dict` looks like this:

```
//dict = {OX:"139.38", LE:"131.28", SA:"105.45"}
```

and we can index into it with the keys

```
dict['LE'] // = "131.28"
```

Comment: And you can do `a[0].indexOf("OX") // => 0` -> The `a[0]` references the first Array within the overall array. Just FYI this is essentially what is called a multidimensional array

Answer (score 0):

This will convert it like this [[""OX", "139.38"], ["LE", "131.28""]] -> ["OX", "LE"]

```
var newArr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    newArr.push(myArr[i][0]);
}
```

This will convert it like this [[""OX", "139.38"], ["LE", "131.28""]] -> ["OX", "139.38", "LE", "131.28"]

```
var newArr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    var tempArr = myArr[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < tempArr.length; j++) {
        newArr.push(tempArr[j]);
    }
}
```

Now you can use indexOf.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get index at outter array:

```
var x = '[["OX", "139.38"], ["LE", "131.28"], ["SA", "105.45"]]';
var y = JSON.parse(x);

function getIndexByKey(key,array){
  for(var i=0, len = array.length; i<len;i++){
    if(array[i][0] === key){
      return i;
    }
  }
}

function getIndexByVal(val,array){
  for(var i=0, len = array.length; i<len;i++){
    if(array[i][1] === val){
      return i;
    }
  }    
}
```

calling it:

```
getIndexByKey('OX', y); //0
getIndexByKey('LE', y); // 1
getIndexByKey('SA', y)  // 2

getIndexByVal('139.38', y); //0
...
```